# angular 2 ajax call getting error "EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: ajax, angular

I'm creating app using angular2 and i need to get weather from yahoo weather. I try to do it using http get method but it's give me a error.

```
import {Component,OnInit,} from "angular2/core";
import {Http}       from "angular2/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
   templateUrl:'app/contact/contact.html',
})

export class ContactComponent{
     constructor (private http: Http) {}
     public url:string= "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2295424";

     ngOnInit(url:string) { 

        return this.http.get(url).map(res => {
                      return res.json();
                   }).subscribe((response) => { console.log(response) });

 }

}
```

Error I get is

> EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

can anyone help me with this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the payload of your response isn't actually JSON. That's why Angular can't parse it. You could have a look within the Network tab of the Chrome developer tools for example for more hints.

I try your request (http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2295424) and I got a 404 response with an HTML payload (and not a JSON one).

A strange thing in your code is the parameter you provide to the `ngOnInit` method. You should try something like that:

```
ngOnInit() { 
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => {
              return res.json();
            }).subscribe((response) => { console.log(response) });
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 6):

You need to append Accept headers to your get request in order for Firefox to render the json that comes back. I found this after searching quite a bit and came across this https://brockallen.com/2012/04/27/change-firefoxs-default-accept-header-to-prefer-json-over-xml/ which led me down the path of adding the headers

```
    ngOnInit() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9');
    return this.http.get(this.url, { headers: headers } ).map(res => {
              return res.json();
            }).subscribe((response) => { console.log(response) });
}
```

Comment: I just want to give you a big ol hug. My angular2 application wasn't working on FF and I could not figure out why. It was the 'Accept': 'application/json' header. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh man, I know these comments are frowned upon, but thank you, this saved me.  Huge digital high 5 for you!